# Why doesn't SIGTERM Works On Windows

Tags: c++, windows

Here is my code:

```
void signalHandler(int sigNum) {
    OutputDebugStringA("i'm terminated\n");
    exit(sigNum);
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    signal(SIGTERM, signalHandler);
    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when i terminated it via the windows taskmgr,that DebugString did't show up.
is something wrong with my code?

Comment: The code is unreadable, please check how to format code in the edit help. You just need to indent with four spaces.

Comment: "The SIGILL and SIGTERM signals are not generated under Windows. They are included for ANSI compatibility." Windows doesn't use unix signals. They are a C runtime concept. Task Manager terminates the application without generating a signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows does not use signals in the same way that Unix systems do.

For example, it [does not generate SIGTERM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`TaskManager` uses `TerminateProcess` API call to kill selected process. Terminated process does not get any notification. So you could not handle it with the `SIGTERM` signal.